# List of all available ARM+DSP processors for surveillance

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, dsp-core, arm

I have come across TI's C6000/Integra. I want to know is there any other similar or better ARM+DSPs available. Specially for surveillance/vehicle number plate recognition etc. Having camera input at least for VGA.

Link: [TI's-Integra](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=dsp&sectionId=2&tabId=2688&familyId=1985)

Comment: This is better suited for [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), but I'm not sure that a "part search" question is even on-topic there.

Comment: Should I re-post it there?

Comment: A moderator will likely move it once they notice it.

Comment: While this question talks about *processor* what is important is to  identify appropriate DSP platform which is relevant for given Image/Video Processing algorithms. It is more relevant here than there because of it's application focus.

Comment: it will be hard to get a 'list of all' processors but nevertheless interesting to see what other people use

Comment: Why constrain yourself to "ARM+DSP"?

Comment: he he @MartinThompson: Then I'll be more than interested to know if there are modules or processors available for the mentioned purpose other than that of ARM+DSP. See I found the given processor already suitable enough however I need to know if anyone else knowing about other processors. Specially with support. I found this too .. seems cost effective: Blackfin's http://newanglewebseminars.com/events/avnet/em/product_demos/vsk3.php .. So anything thing else? :)

Answer (score 2):

As you mention other non-ARM options in the comments, here's a few:

- [Blackfin](http://www.analog.com/en/processors-dsp/blackfin/processors/index.html)
- Xilinx's [Zynq (ARM+FPGA)](http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/epp/zynq-7000/index.htm)
- Altera also do a [similar ARM+FPGA](http://www.altera.com/devices/processor/arm/cortex-a9/m-arm-cortex-a9.html)
- Some of Freescale's [i.MX51](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/taxonomy.jsp?nodeId=018rH3ZrDR633B) processors might be suitable (ARM+co-processor, not a true DSP) - although I'm not sure if there's out-of-the-box surveillance software
- And of course, there's always the PC+GPU option, depending on your power, cost, size, weight constraints

Comment: How about : http://www.marvell.com/embedded-processors/